# How to view source code of F# in Xamarin Studio on Mac OS?

Tags: f#, xamarin-studio

F# code:

```
let s = "123"
let b = s.Contains "1"
printfn "Hello World!"
```

When I select `Contains` and click "Go to Declaration", the Xamarin display:

```
using System;

public bool Contains (string value); //like a abstract method, no method body
```

when I select `printfn` and "Go to Declaration", the Xamarin display:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion ("4.4.0.0")]
[assembly: AutoOpen ("Microsoft.FSharp")]
[assembly: AutoOpen ("Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.IntrinsicOperators")]
[assembly: AutoOpen ("Microsoft.FSharp.Core")]
[assembly: AutoOpen ("Microsoft.FSharp.Collections")]
[assembly: AutoOpen ("Microsoft.FSharp.Control")]
[assembly: AutoOpen ("Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryRunExtensions.LowPriority")]
[assembly: AutoOpen ("Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryRunExtensions.HighPriority")]
[assembly: FSharpInterfaceDataVersion (2, 0, 0)]
[assembly: CLSCompliant (true)]
[assembly: Debuggable (DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints)]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright ("© Microsoft Corporation and other contributors.  Apache 2.0 License.")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription ("FSharp.Core.dll")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct ("F# (open edition)")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle ("FSharp.Core.dll")]
[assembly: DefaultDependency (LoadHint.Always)]
[assembly: Dependency ("FSharp.Core", LoadHint.Always)]
[assembly: ComVisible (false)]
[assembly: ComVisible (false)]
[assembly: SecurityTransparent]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(AggregateException))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(IStructuralComparable))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(IStructuralEquatable))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(IObservable))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(IObserver))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Lazy))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(BigInteger))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(CancellationToken))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(CancellationTokenRegistration))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(CancellationTokenSource))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Tuple))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Tuple))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Tuple))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Tuple))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Tuple))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Tuple))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Tuple))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Tuple))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo (typeof(Tuple))]
```

Is there any way to view source code of F#?

Comment: Well, it is all on github

Comment: @JohnPalmer can you provide a link for source code of F#? and can I add source code to my project or to Xamarin studio?

Comment: No idea about how to get it working in Xamarin, but github.com/fsharp/fsharp has the source.  Why do you want to see it anyway?

Comment: @JohnPalmer Thank you for your reply!